Counting the number of singularites in Rudin RCA 10.41 and 10.42
Here is the Rudin's book:
The Calculus of Residues
10.41 Definition
A function $f$ is said to be meromorphic in an open set $\Omega$ if there is a set $A \subset \Omega$ such that
(a) $A$ has no limit point in $\Omega$,
(b) $f \in H(\Omega-A)$,
(c) $f$ has a pole at each point of $A$.
Note that the possibility $A=\varnothing$ is not excluded. Thus every $f \in H(\Omega)$ is meromorphic in $\Omega$.
Note also that (a) implies that no compact subset of $\Omega$ contains infinitely many points of $A$, and that $A$ is therefore at most countable.
If $f$ and $A$ are as above, if $a \in A$, and if
$$
Q(z)=\sum_{k=1}^m c_k(z-a)^{-k}
$$
is the principal part of $f$ at $a$, as defined in Theorem 10.21 (i.e., if $f-Q$ has a removable singularity at $a$ ), then the number $c_1$ is called the residue of $f$ at $a$ :
$$
c_1=\operatorname{Res}(f ; a) .
$$
If $\Gamma$ is a cycle and $a \notin \Gamma^*,(1)$ implies
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\Gamma} Q(z) d z=c_1 \operatorname{Ind}_{\Gamma}(a)=\operatorname{Res}(Q ; a) \operatorname{Ind}_{\Gamma}(a) .
$$
This very special case of the following theorem will be used in its proof.
10.42 The Residue Theorem
Suppose $f$ is a meromorphic function in $\Omega$. Let $A$ be the set of points in $\Omega$ at which $f$ has poles. If $\Gamma$ is a cycle in $\Omega-A$ such that
$$
\operatorname{Ind}_{\Gamma}(\alpha)=0 \quad \text { for all } \quad \alpha \notin \Omega,
$$
then
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\Gamma} f(z) d z=\sum_{a \in A} \operatorname{Res}(f ; a) \operatorname{Ind}_{\Gamma}(a) .
$$
Proof. Let $B=\left\{a \in A: \operatorname{Ind}_{\Gamma}(a) \neq 0\right\}$. Let $W$ be the complement of $\Gamma^*$. Then $\operatorname{Ind}_{\Gamma}(z)$ is constant in each component $V$ of $W$. If $V$ is unbounded, or if $V$ intersects $\Omega^c$, (1) implies that $\operatorname{Ind}_{\Gamma}(z)=0$ for every $z \in V$. Since $A$ has no limit point in $\Omega$, we conclude that $B$ is a finite set.
The sum in (2), though formally infinite, is therefore actually finite.
My questions:

Why do we have $A$ is at most countable?

How can I deduce that $B$ is a finite set from $A$ has no limit point?



Every $a \in A$ is “isolated in $\Omega$”, i.e. there is a an open neighborhood $U_a$ with $a \in U_a \subset \Omega$ which does not contain any other point of $A$: $U_a \cap A = \{ a \}$. (If such a neighborhood $U_a$ would not exist then we could choose $a_n \in A \setminus \{a \}$ with $a_n \to a$, contradicting the fact that $A$ has no limit point in $\Omega$.)
Each $U_a$ contains a point with rational coordinates. Since there are only countably many complex numbers with rational coordiates there are at most countably many $U_a$, which implies that there are at most countably many $a \in A$.
Now let $V$ be the unbounded component of $\Bbb C \setminus \Gamma^*$. We know that $\operatorname{Ind}_{\Gamma}(z)=0$ for all $z \in V$. Therefore $B \subset K := \Bbb C\setminus V$. $K$ is a compact set and therefore contains at most finitely many points of $A$. So $B = K \cap A$ is a finite set (possibly empty).

@LucaHao: Your question is not clear to me. It is given that $A$ has no limit points in $\Omega$.

sorry, I want to say prove A is at most countable from a compact view
